# MVC4: Extract whole website files while running

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to update my website by extracting a zip file which contains whole files of the website itself. Apparently the system does not allow me to do this as such folders are protected:

> Error while extrating: Access to the path
>   'C:\WebsiteFolder\Website\bin\' is denied.

I also think that changing the dlls will restart the server while extracting. Is there a way to do this? To extract all files then restarts the server after it finishes. Also the web.config might be overwritten while extracting the zip file.

Does putting offline.htm help?

Comment: I think you need to look at your approach, maybe consider using msdeploy to deploy a packaged zip file?  This would managed it automatically then, but it would need to be triggered from another source.

Comment: The whole idea is that i have a CMS application like wordpress, joomla, etc. I want to be able to update the application while running, automatically from the standalone CMS app.

Answer (score 0):

This is because IIS is using files within the bin directory, and the AppPool is likely running as system, or an administrator account.

Stopping IIS (or the app pool) will enable you to replace the files.

> I also think that changing the dlls will restart the server while extracting

Yes, it will restart the app pool when you change these files

Comment: Does the restarting happen immediately after a a copy of dll being placed in the bin folder? Or does the system wait until the current user request which copying the dlls finishes first, then restart?